# Get the Id/Name of a JS Created Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I am using the clone command to dynamically create new HTML elements. The code creates a new parent with all its children, and each child gets a new name and id (current name/id +1). This is working fine as, when I post the form, I see the new, correct names.

Within this, I am using an image to redirect the click from the input=file so that the input=file button is customized. But, currently, clicking any of the images calls the same, original file=upload.

I need to know the id/name of the file=upload--whether it is the original or a clone, but I seem to only be getting the original name, even if a clone is clicked.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/msith718/xfuv79b3/71/

```
  $(document).on('click', '.uploadBtn', function(){
    alert( this.id );
  });
```

Click on the + to create new clones, and then the image to try to get the name/id of which one was clicked. It seems to always be the same name.

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your alert with this one, if you want the parent with the changing id.

```
alert( $(this).closest('.fingers').attr('id') );
```

Comment: hmm. that seems to work. Now, I should be able to parse the result (finger2) to remove the "finger" and be left with "2". Then I can concatenate to call the click on "uploadBtnOld2" instead of "uploadBtnOld"... right? Or is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

That is because your id creation code is wrong.

You do

```
var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
var id = this.id || "";
var match = id.match(regex) || [];
if (match.length == 3) {
  //snipped code
}
```

The code inside the `if` is never executed for the button because `this.id` is `imgButton` so the regex does not match it, as it expects it to end in a number.

The easiest solution would be to add 0 to the end of the first button id, thus making it `imgButton0`. Your code would run from then on.

Updated demo at https://jsfiddle.net/xfuv79b3/76/

Comment: This is indeed better.

Comment: Thank you so much!! My javascript is not the strongest and I pulled this together from code I found in various spots, and this last part was driving me crazy. Now I think I see why. I had the brackets just because that was what was in the code I had found. This seems to be just what I need. I should be able to click the correct file=upload now. Once again, thank you so much.

Comment: ok, so another question. Maybe I can make this even easier. My plan was, once I know the id of the image, I would parse out the image name and be left with just the number. Then concatenate that number to the id of the file upload and call the correct one. Is there a way to get the id of the file upload (by class?) that is in the same parent as the image?

Comment: well in your current html structure you do not even need the `id`. Since it is the exact previous element, you can do `$(this).prev()` and that would give you the file input element. (*keep in mind that you have 2 `id` attributes on the file input and that is invalid*)

Comment: the 2 ids were a typo. thanks. As for the prev. I guess I didnt realize that javascript will read each element in the order it is created in the HTML. Is that the way it works? In which case prev works as long as the two elements I am working with are consecutive?

Comment: @msith718 yes. But `prev` is a jQuery method that will get the immediately preceding element. (see https://api.jquery.com/prev/)